# Android/Gradle: from which folders are files merged or overridden?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, merge, android-productflavors

Developing an Android project with Android Studio and Gradle and using flavors, some folders have their contents replaced with the files from the most specific flavor, whereas files in other folders are replaced (i.e. files are not merged into one):

So, for files with the same name across different flavors:

```
java/* (files are replaced)
res/layout (files are replaced)
res/values (files are merged)
res/xml (files are ...replaced???)
```

How can we tell which resources will be merged and which ones will be replaced?